# How to omit "--multiprocess" option in pytest in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am seeing sporadic instances of the following code being executed in `python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py`  happening when running `Pytest`  in debug mode in `Pycharm`

```
def _check_not_importing_main():
    if getattr(process.current_process(), '_inheriting', False):
        raise RuntimeError('''
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
```

I had never seen this before.

Is there any way to disable `--multiprocess` when running `pytest` in `pycharm` - as an intended workaround?

The command line being generated is

````
venv/bin/python3 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py 
  --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 50192 --file ```

I am on `Pycharm 2022.3.1 Professional Edition`
````

Answer (score 0):

The code that starts the additional threads, in general, should only be called by the main thread. (There are exceptions.). This code should either be inside `if __name__ == "__main__"` or inside a function that is called from within the `if __name__ == "__main__"`.

This message is warning you that you've got a top-level call that is starting new processes. That is a mistake.

Comment: I'm not doing any of that, `pytest` is the one launching any threads.  I'd like to actually disable multithreading for `pytest` here